# Implementing CSS in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Assuming that one is developing a web application which is sufficiently non-intensive that overhead is not a concern. Is it reasonable to implement CSS solely in Javascript/jQuery and completely abandon external css files?

```
$('<div/>').attr({'id':'special_box'}).addClass('little_box').appendTo('body')
$('<div/>').addClass('little_box').appendTo('body')
$('<div/>').addClass('little_box').appendTo('body')
...
$('.little_box').css({'color':'red'})
$('#special_box').css({'color':'blue'})
```

Is there anybody advocating this complete conflation? Is there anything that completely prevents it or makes it evidently unreasonable?

---

**EDIT**

The unreasonableness, as helpfully explained below, is that the jQuery css function is creating styles that are being applied to the individual element and not creating/augmenting master css rules as I'd assumed.

Although there do appear to be [ways](http://www.happycode.info/create-css-classes-with-javascript/) to [achieve](https://github.com/kajic/jquery-injectCSS) this [conflation](http://flesler.blogspot.co.uk/2007/11/jqueryrule.html). I am not qualified to analyse them. Thanks all.

Comment: Argh... No... Don't... Maintenance nightmare ahead... :)

Comment: It's a pretty bad idea.

Comment: Just one: the existence of the browser's own native implementation of CSS.

Comment: Using JavaScript to set ALL your css is like using a light switch to activate a robot that paints your room.

Comment: Also: what if the user has JavaScript disabled for some reason? Static CSS will still be rendered; dynamic CSS will not.

Comment: @Blazemonger The divs above wouldn't be drawn either, this is a hypothetical web application which is contingent on JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not reasonable, not only because it is slow (as you'd expect), any `.css` calls involving classes, e.g. `$('.little_box').css(...)`, will apply css to only elements of that class that exist at the time, not `.little_box`es created in the future.

Answer (score 0):

why do you want to complicate yourself while development, CSS is far easy and better to use than doing css through javascript or jQuery.

Comment: I don't want to, I'm asking theoretically.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from being very time consuming to physically code, you CAN do this. However, it's alot more intensive than CSS and prevents alot of the advantages of CSS.

It's like building an oil rig and oil refinery to fill your car up. You could do it, but why not just go to the petrol station?

Answer (score 0):

I would not advocate this complete conflation - certainly for the reasons that others have already stated, but also for these two reasons:

1) If your application grows and has multiple .js files then it will create an additional headache if you try to implement modular loading of the files using something like [require.js](http://requirejs.org/)

2) Again, if your application ever grew very large or you decided you wanted to, it would make it more work to start using [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/)

As I'm sure is becoming apparent, the cons massively outweigh the (dubious) pros of this idea.

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely possible to build a site that way, but it will be more work to do it, and also more work to maintain it. So, there is nothing that completely prevents it, but depending on the amount of styles it may be so much extra work that it would be unreasonable.

There is also a performance factor. CSS stands for cascading style sheets, and with such an approach you would lose both "cascading" and "sheets", left with only the style. In practice that means that you apply each style to each element instead of specifying rules that apply to multiple elements. The jQuery selectors can help you to apply the same style to multiple elements, but it will still loop through them and apply the style to each single element.

As this happens in the browser, you may get a noticable delay when the page loads. Also, the styles would be applied after all the elements are created instead of already be there when the elements come into existance, so the visitor may see the page being displayed completely without styling for a shoft while, then freeze completely while the styles are applied, before it displays correctly.